# Why doesn't Software Center prompt for root creds?

Tags: permissions, software-center, 18.04

I've got an installation of Ubuntu 18.04.  It's a default, simple installation.  It's been patched successfully using `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`, and 
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y`.

I don't understand what the point of Software Center is.  It's pinned to Favorites by default.  When you search for something, Ubuntu's search suggests packages to install via Software Center...and yet...

1. Software Center needs `sudo` credentials to do anything.
2. Software Center doesn't prompt the user for `sudo -y creds`.
3. Software Center *always* just tells me "You do not have permission to install software".

[image]

Clearly, just clicking on the icon for Software Center is not the right way to start Software Center.  It seems like it could be a handy tool so...what *is* the right way to start Software Center?  Is there any way to have it prompt you for `sudo -y` credentials on start?

Comment: Not entirely a True Statement. It depends on what your installing as some things do require root password.

Comment: Are you using the X session or the Wayland session?

Comment: "Ubuntu Software Centre" was for 16.04 (& earlier/Unity), and was replaced with Ubuntu Software (or really Software, a GNOME app) which is the intended 18.04.  If I use [gnome-|ubuntu-]'Software' it runs without password, but asks me to enter password when I click 'install'

Comment: Ubuntu Software asks for password when you install any software but not for browsing or searching. This is a feature. It looks like you prefer that it asks for password when it is stated, like synaptic does. That would be a feature request. Bug reports and feature requests are off topic here. Asking why a software has or do not have a specific feature could only give opinion based answers from users. Such questions are not suitable for this site.

Comment: Are you the only user of this system? How were you granted `sudo` rights?)

Comment: It kind of sounds like some of you are saying that Ubuntu Software *should* prompt me for a password but for some reason *isn't* prompting me for a password.  Does that sound right?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, I have no idea if I'm using X session or Wayland session.  How would I determine this?  I did a default install of Ubuntu 18.04 (aka. I chose the defaults and just kept clicking 'next' until it was done).

Comment: @muru, I'm the only user on this system and I believe I have sudo rights because I can do sudo's from Terminal.

Comment: @user68186 you misunderstood OP's question. The app does not require the password but gives a "not authorized" error straight away.

Comment: @benday, then probably you are using the X session. At the login window you have a dropdown menu where you have the choice so you can check.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Based on the comments so far, you may be right.  I will retract my close vote.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error you get. I opened **Ubuntu Software** and searched for `shutter`. Then I clicked the **Install** button. Immediately I was asked to enter the password.  See the screenshot at https://imgur.com/EORDdfp and note, I am running Ubuntu in a virtual machine for testing. It may be useful if you could take a screenshot of the Ubuntu Software app by pressing Alt+PrintScreen buttons together, and upload it in imgur website. Then edit the question above and add the link to the screenshot.

Comment: @user68186 -- video clip posted.  https://imgur.com/a/y1AIBGB

Comment: Thanks for the video. Now I see whats happening, but I don't know why.

Comment: have you found a solution for this? I'm running into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try running the software center from command line using

```
sudo ubuntu-software
```

see if this works.

Comment: you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by:

```
killall gnome-software
sudo -i gnome-software
```